# Object literal reusable function

Tags: javascript

Please find the below code for more information.

```
var person = {
    firstname:"john",
    lastname:"doe",
    greet: function(){
        return "hello " + this.firstname + " " + this.lastname; 
    }
}

console.log(person.greet());
```

How can I make above object literal function `greet()` dymanic? Like I can pass params values for example `person.greet('jessie','jay')` will return `hello jessie jay`

Is it better to use constructor method (instances) in order to make function dynamic and reusable? I found that object literal is just to organize code.

Comment: just pass parameters and use it.

Comment: Object literals are about a lot more than just organising code. That is but one of their uses.

Comment: @GregL What else it can do?

Comment: It depends *how* you use the object. If you plan on having many instances of this kind of object, then consider making this more of a *'class'* type object with a constructor. If this is only used sparingly, then your object literal will suffice. Unless you're using 1000s of these objects, the performance implications are negligible, it's more about best practises.

Comment: This example does not make much sense. Either you want to call a `greet` function on an object that stores its own data as you did, or you want to call a pure `greet` function that needs all data as argument and should not be a method of an object at all. You sould give us a real world example. What do you really mean with `make dynamic`?

Comment: While you shouldn't be using an object literal in this instance, your object literal is wrong. Properties (in this case `firstname:"john"`, etc.) are separated by commas `,` not semicolons `;`. Just something to keep in mind for the correct uses of object literals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should think about what `person` and `greet` actually is or should be. If `person` is an object and `greet` a method that operates on the data of that object, the way you've written `person` is fine.

If you consider `person` to be some kind of namespace or module you will use to organize your code, you will write `greet` as a pure function that doesn't depend on and modify any variables out of its scope. In this case you won't have person instance data as firstname and lastname on `person`.

```
var person = {
    greet: function(person){
        return "hello " + person.firstName+ " " + person.lastName; 
    }
};  

var jenny = { firstName : 'Jennifer', lastName : 'IdowntKnow' };
person.greet(jenny);
```

A combination of both will be very confusing in this case

```
var person = {
    firstname:"john",
    lastname:"doe",
    greet: function(firstName, lastName){
        /* .. */
    }
};

person.greet('Jennifer', 'IdowntKnow');  
// hmm, what happens here? Person switched to Jennifer now? What about john? weird code...
```

The question if you should use a constructor function is more about performance or if you need features like prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Liked this answer too.

Answer (score 5):

I'll suggest you to use Constructor function. This pattern is called as [Factory pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-factory-pattern/). The function here acts as *class* and for each person a new object can be created.

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function () {
    return 'Hello ' + this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
};

var jon = new Person('Jon', 'Skeet');
var tushar = new Person('Tushar', 'Jadhav');

console.log(jon.greet()); // Hello Jon Skeet
console.log(tushar.greet()); // Hello Tushar Jadhav
```

Comment: so I will use alot of prototype? what if I have a hundred function, that will all go into prototype?

Comment: You didn't answer their questions about passing parameters to the `greet ` function.

Comment: @jusopi It did the answer. Perfect.

Comment: @Jennifer You can define the function on prototype and then the same function will be called for each instance.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal reread the question.  It specifically asks *"How can I make above object literal function greet() dymanic? Like I can pass params values for example `person.greet('jessie','jay')` will return 'hello jessie jay'"* This answer provides no means of addressing function parameters.  It only answers the 2nd part.

Answer (score -2):

```
greet: function(fname, lname){
    return "hello " +fname + " " + lname; 
}
```

if you also want to update firstname and lastname

```
greet: function(fname, lname){
    this.firstname =fname;
    this.latname =lname;
    return "hello " +fname + " " + lname; 
}
```

Comment: The part about `this` won't work unless you create it as a prototype function. Better remove that to prevent downvotes :)

Comment: @ jrharshath i didn't get you. what is the problem in this code?